# Saving function arguments to a mock method from a EXPECT_CALL

Tags: c++, callback, googletest

I have a class that "subscribes" to a signal from a component by calling subscribe(callbackfunction). I am now trying to test this behaviour with gtest/gmock by saving the callback and send data to it later to test other parts of that component.

gtest code:

```
using callback = std::function<void(const int*)>;
callback cb;

EXPECT_CALL(*mock_data, Subscribe).WillOnce(SaveArg<0>(cb));
```

gmock code (mock_data):

```
MOCK_METHOD(bool, Subscribe, (std::function<void(const int*)> cb), (const));
```

And I am getting this from the compiler:

```
error: cannot convert ‘testing::internal::SaveArgAction<0, std::function<void(const int*)> >’ to ‘const testing::Action<bool(std::function<void(const int*)>)>&’
```

Is there a way to actually do what I want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SaveArg<N>(pointer)`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/refs/heads/77A9B20B4C1E02FAC90D1D942E1D4C18/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md) expects a location/pointer where to store an argument.

```
EXPECT_CALL(*mock_data, Subscribe).WillOnce(SaveArg<0>(&cb));
```